# How to show hyperlinks in text area of angular application

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a text area box for dynamic content in an angular application.  If some of that content includes a hyperlink, it is not recognized and is therefore unclickable.  How can I display a hyperlink within a text box in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot.

You'll need to use a div. You can also use contenteditable to allow users to modify the content of the div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

However, this will only work if the user copy and pastes a hyperlink into the editable div. Otherwise you will need to use the key events and regex to detect if a user entered a hyperlink.

Depending on the use case you may want to consider not hyperlinking in the text area and instead do something like what stackoverflow does and show preview below the textarea and use code to detect and hyperlink URLs.

Optionally there are third party libraries like QuillJS and TinyMCE.